# Java library to parse Latex source file

Tags: java

Is there any java library that can extract title, keywords and abstract from latex source file.
Something which works similar to jsoup library that returns html tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: TeX is a language of sufficient complexity and dynamically changing syntax, so I doubt that the task can be solved in its entirety without involving a TeX compiler. There might be however limited solutions processing some subset of the language (which is quite typical in, say, scientific articles).

Comment: As long as the abstract is written as en environment, it is easy enough to extract. Title can be more complex because of brace levels.